# redirect to some page and than come back to the script

Tags: php, redirect

Can somehow be managed to redirect to some page using header and after some time to get back to the script and redirect to some another page over and over?!

i use it as localhost on my pc i read urls from text file and i need to redirect to them one by one, that's why i need to come back to the script automatically after redirection

Comment: thats easy just test it! I think this work will damage your server

Comment: Is the redirect target your own server/script which you have access to and can modify it? Or is it a foreign one. In last case you cannot do it...

Comment: i use it as localhost on my pc i read urls from text file and i need to redirect to them one by one, that's why i need to come back to the script automatically after redirection

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop to link to both pages by simply doing this on both pages:

```
sleep(5); //for 5 seconds
header("location: anotherphpfile.php");
```

Comment: i use it as localhost on my pc i read urls from text file and i need to redirect to them one by one, that's why i need to come back to the script automatically after redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

For testing just do this:

1-Create a page and rename it **p1.php**

```
  <?php
      //This is p1.php
      header("location:p1.php");
   ?>
```

2-Create another page and rename it **p2.php**

```
<?php
    //This is p2.php
    header("location:p1.php");
?>
```

3-Now run the **p1.php**

*This is the Result in diffrent browsers:*

[image: SAFARI]

[image: Chrome]

[image: Internet Explorer]

[image: FireFox]

and if you are going to get a URL and then fetch some information from that page use this function:

**file_get_contents** and then fetch information from that page, This is what Google and other search engines do.